# C printf to custom hardware

Tags: c, printf, stdout

I have existing code with various debug messages.  Our embedded system does not have an external connection for a terminal.  I want to modify the printf so that its output goes to a memory location, rather than STDOUT,  which is mapped to a FIFO.  I guess I need to find write my own outbyte/outnum. Just cant seem to find the GNU code where I can grab things.

I am running a microblaze processor inside an Xilinx FPGA.  All print statements are for debugging.  We are running GNU tools (Xilinx SDK).  For development, was able stick an UART in the design and wire the uart to a few test points.

As we get ready to deploy, I will no longer have this visibility. We do have a USB-to-Serial connecton, but it looks like a fifo, not a serial port to the embedded system. We have a protocol for sending messages over this link.  I was thinking of adding a debug message to our protocol.  I would like to redirect my print statement to a buffer, and then process this buffer.

I was trying to take the existing printf (xil_printf) and create my own cc_printf, by rewriting the outbyte code, but just not able to dig down in the code far enough to see how to do it. (Frankly, I am VHDL/hardware guy).

Overall code size is tens of thousands of lines of C code.  My section is maybe 3-4 thousand lines of code.  The basic operation is for software/hardware updates of the system to come in via the USB port and moved to FLASH memory. My code parses incoming packets coming over the USB-to-serial link.  Basically there is a bit set that tells me that there is a packet ready in a receive buffer.  I process the packet and write to FLASH.  As part of the protocol, there are ACK/NACKs/ABorts.  I currently use the printf to printout statuses to my lab bench version of the system.

As stated, I would like to embed these printouts into our protocol.  I am not married to printf, and would use some other print-function. I would like to print out messages and data.  If something else would be a better starting point, I am fine with that.  It seems that the biggest issue for me is grabbing the output of the print and directing it where to go.

Comment: `fprintf`? `dprintf`?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to use stdio.h on embedded systems. You are probably better off using some generic UART printing routine. Your MCU likely comes with app notes that shows how to quickly whip together a UART driver.

Comment: What kind and size of code (thousands of source code lines)? What embedded system target? How do you compile it? With what compiler? Please **edit your question** to improve & motivate it!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and thoroughly read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) - in particular, ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Even after the edit, we still have no idea about code size & purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `printf`  *directly*, for debugging purposes.

Use a macro, perhaps something like

```
#define DEBUGPRINTF(Fmt,...) do \
   {printf("%s:%d: " Fmt "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__,  __VA_ARGS__);} while(0)
```

Then, once you have converted all your debug `printf`  (and only these) to `DEBUGPRINTF` you just need to change the definition of that macro (e.g. on the embedded system, perhaps using `snprintf` ...).

So in the rest of your code, replace a `printf("debugging x=%d\n", x);`  with `DEBUGPRINTF("debugging x=%d", x);` but do that only for *debugging* prints. BTWK 4KLOC (for your part) is really tiny, and even 200KLOC (for the whole thing) is small enough to make that replacement doable "by hand" (e.g. Emacs "find & replace interactively").

<sup>(I am guessing that you are first developing a small piece of code -a few thousand lines- on your laptop, and later porting it to the embedded system)</sup>

Once you have converted all your *debug* `printf`  to `DEBUGPRINTF` (and only the debugging prints!) you can redefine that macro, perhaps *inspired* by

```
#define DEBUGPRINTF(Fmt,...) do \
  {snprintf(debugbuffer, sizeof(debugbuffer), Fmt, __VA_ARGS__); } while(0)
```

<sup>(I guess that you'll need to add something more in that macro -probably before the closing brace- to actually *send* the debug output -that is the content of `debugbuffer`- somewhere, but how to do that is implementation & system specific)</sup>

But more likely you'll disable the debug printf with

```
#define DEBUGPRINTF(Fmt,...) do{}while(0)
```

BTW, the embedded target system might not even have any `snprintf` ...

If you want to study some *readable* C standard library implementation (on Linux) consider looking inside [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) source code. You'll need to understand what [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) are.

Actually, you should in fact write and debug your code on your laptop (e.g. running Linux) and only put on the embedded system something which you believe has no bugs. In practice, avoid deploying code with debug printfs (or think in advance of something much better). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22973127/841108).

> It seems that the biggest issue for me is grabbing the output of the print and directing it where to go.

Probably use `snprintf`  then "send" the `debugbuffer`  to the appropriate place using appropriate primitives. With [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)  you know the size of the message (e.g. with the return value from `snprintf`  and/or using `%n` in the format control string). Or have your own logging or debugging [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) (using [`<stdarg.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_start)  and `va_start` etc  ....)

Do not confuse debugging messages with [logging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logfile) messages. If you want logging, design it carefully. But debugging messages should probably be removed at deployment time.

Comment: It's probably good advice, but it doesn't actually answer the question; so the next person searching finds this question, and maybe this advice doesn't apply to his situation.  Maybe good info for a comment instead of an answer imo

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: That does not fit in a comment, and I have no idea (only guesses) about the OP code and target system.

Comment: The essential info in the ORIGINAL answer (as it looked when I commented) would fit in a comment, actually.  And regardless, it still doesn't answer the question asked; sorry if you disagree.

Comment: The question by OP is actually not precise enough to get any meaningful answer. I asked (in a comment for the question) the OP to edit his question to improve it, and he did not do that (yet).

Comment: All the reasons in the world don't change the basic fact, that I don't believe your response answered the question asked.  If you're saying you couldn't answer the question as asked, then my solution would be to not post something as an answer.  Again, sorry if you don't agree.

Comment: Updated question with more detail.  Note that the system has no OS or filesystem

Comment: @PaulGigliotti: We still don't know the size & purpose of your code.

Comment: Debug messages does not mean bugs in the code.  Lets say they are status messages, so that I can see what is happening in the system, should something come up.

Comment: Then it is called *logging* (or *log messages*) and should be designed as such.

Comment: I added additional detail to the original question, with info on code size and function.

Comment: Ok, logging. It started as debug, and morphing into logging. Seemed that the easiest way forward was to modify the printfs, such that I could use that output for logging.

Answer (score 1):

The Posix function `fmemopen` allows you to open a memory buffer like a file and returns a `FILE *` that can be used with the standard IO functions, like `fprintf`.  As far as printing to a device that's not a serial port, I don't know what OS (of any) you are running on, but if present you could write a stream device driver for that custom device and set your `stdout` and `stderr` (and maybe `stdin`) to that.  If you're running without an OS then somewhere someone has created a `FILE` structure that in interfacing with the serial port somehow, and `printf` is using that.